# Restore the order in which data is put into a JSONObject

Tags: android, json

i want to have json as it is inserted in this code but it works something different! i first want `CustomerID` and then `Name` but this json gives the `Name` first and then `CustomerID`. i have inserted the json as i want but why it gives different result please help me..

```
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject();

    try {
        json.put("CustomerID", "069C21F1-EE87-4FB4-A129-478AEAA454FF");
        json.put("Name", "Name_" + (int) Math.random() * 1000);
} catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: im not using right now but in debugging i saw that order is not maintained and as per requirement i need them to b in order

Comment: why you should care about the order , the JsonObject uses a HashMap to store it data , so if you want a value you should provide a key for it

Comment: actually im posting this json to url and at the server it is being parsed in order so...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That is the expected behavior of a JSONObject. By its definition, it says:

**An object as an unordered set of name/value pairs**

however if you want it to be ordered do this:

```
1. prepare a LinkedHashMap object with elements

2. convert it to JSONObject
```

**Example:**

```
Map obj = new LinkedHashMap();
obj.put("a", "String1");
obj.put("b", new Integer(1));
obj.put("c", new Boolean(true));
obj.put("d", "String2");
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(obj);
```

**EDIT:**

download this library:

https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-java

save all the files in a new package in your project

instead of using **org.json.JSONObject** use **your.package.JSONObject** which you added from the downloaded library.

now open **JSONObject.java** file and change **HashMap()** to **LinkedHashMap()** in the constructor

```
public JSONObject(Map map)
```

Comment: i know n thanks. but how can i make the JsonArray by this LinkedHashMap ? please help me..

Answer (score 1):

You can put that Name before CustomerID line to satisfy yourself, but that wont make a difference at all. Because the data from json is extracted in the form of key value pairs. Its independent of the order  its placed in.

Comment: ya i had tried it but i want to make json as it is inserted.. do u know how?

Answer (score 0):

You can use accumulative()

See [android developpers refference](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#accumulate%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%29)

Answer (score 0):

[A useful answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29491895/1593398)

[Gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) if your friend. This will print the ordered map into an ordered JSON string.

I used the latest version of Gson (2.3.1), you can can download it via the following options at the bottom of this post.

```
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import com.google.gson.Gson;

public class OrderedJson {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Create a new ordered map.
        Map<String,String> myLinkedHashMap = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();

        // Add items, in-order, to the map.
        myLinkedHashMap.put("1", "first");
        myLinkedHashMap.put("2", "second");
        myLinkedHashMap.put("3", "third");

        // Instantiate a new Gson instance.
        Gson gson = new Gson();

        // Convert the ordered map into an ordered string.
        String json = gson.toJson(myLinkedHashMap, LinkedHashMap.class);

        // Print ordered string.
        System.out.println(json); // {"1":"first","2":"second","3":"third"}
    }
}
```

**Dependency Options
Maven**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
    <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.1</version>
</dependency>
```

**Gradle**

```
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1'
```

Or you can visit [Maven Central](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Ccom.google.code.gson%7Cgson%7C2.3.1%7Cjar) for more download options.