# Storing arrays or lists in edge/vertex properties Graph database?

Tags: ibm-cloud, graph-databases

How do I store arrays/lists in edge/vertex property values ?

Thanks,

Comment: Is it possible to write a custom serializer ? I would like to store a java.util.LinkedHashMap Object.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying this in IBM Graph ? As of now, the types that are supported in IBM Graph are the primitive data types : string , long, double and boolean. Your best option would be to convert/serialize that object into a string and store that as a property of your edge/vertex.

Comment: Hi Mahmoud, Can you elaborate a bit on the serialization ttechnique. Can you give me link to the tutorial. Yes I am using IBM graph database. Thanks

Comment: The idea is converting the object to JSON format and store that JSON object as a string in a vertex or edge property. If you're using org.json for example , you can do `String jsonString = new JSONObject(data).toString()`. [Check this question in SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22870584/convert-from-linkedhashmap-to-json-string) and this one for [ordered JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29491281/building-ordered-json-string-from-linkedhashmap)