# JSON causing unprocessable entity when submitting to Rails (Error 422)

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails, json, mongodb

I'm using an android app to submit to a Rails app with a Mongo backend hosted on Heroku.  I am able to use the form online to submit a new item into the mongo database, but when I try to submit JSON from an android app I get:

`{"error":"Unprocessable Entity","status":"422"}`

I think this may have to do with the order of JSON when I submit as it seems to have gotten mixed up in order which I realized is normal according to [a past SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12672180/restore-the-order-in-which-data-is-put-into-a-jsonobject).  But, the solution on that question did not work for me.

Here is the construction of the JSONObject in my Android app:

```
 JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        jsonObject.put("ph", 2);
        jsonObject.put("chlorine", 2.0);
        jsonObject.put("magnified_Link", url);//URLEncoder.encode(encodedImage, "UTF-8"));
        jsonObject.put("taste", "yucky");
        jsonObject.put("odor", "smelly");
        jsonObject.put("temperature", "77.0");
        jsonObject.put("mercury", 234);
        jsonObject.put("hardness", 9.0);
        jsonObject.put("lat", latitude);
        jsonObject.put("long", longitude);

        String json = jsonObject.toString(); // Output to string
        Log.d(TAG, json);

        StringEntity se = new StringEntity(json);
        // put json string into server
        httpPost.setEntity(se);

        //httpPost.setHeader("Authorization", "Client-ID " +API_KEY);
        httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
```

This is how the JSON appears in my android app when I log it before submission:

```
{"chlorine":2,"odor":"smelly","magnified_Link":"http:\/\/i.imgur.com\/JnbuUwy.jpg","long":0,"hardness":9,"ph":2,"taste":"yucky","lat":0,"mercury":234,"temperature":"77.0"}
```

This is how my JSON page looks like on my rails app with one successful submission into it through the online rails app:

```
[{"id":{"$oid":"558766f26633380003000000"},"ph":1.0,"chlorine":2.0,"magnified_Link":"3","taste":"4","odor":"5","temperature":6.0,"mercury":7.0,"hardness":8.0,"lat":40.7127,"long":-74.0059,"url":"https://distributed-health.herokuapp.com/distributed_healths/558766f26633380003000000.json"}]
```

Finally here is the model for a "DistributedHealth" (my object) in my rails app:

```
class DistributedHealth
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :ph, type: Float
  field :chlorine, type: Float
  field :magnified_Link, type: String
  field :taste, type: String
  field :odor, type: String
  field :temperature, type: Float
  field :mercury, type: Float
  field :hardness, type: Float
  field :lat, type: Float
  field :long, type: Float
end
```

I can include any other relevant code and will make edits to this post as I continue trying to solve this issue.

Thank you,

Clayton.

EDIT: I have the error message from my heroku server

```
2015-06-23T21:29:34.382730+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/distributed_healths.json" host=distributed-health.herokuapp.com request_id=2dcde4a4-3dcc-4381-98ba-6ca399400a6d fwd="128.54.58.245" dyno=web.1 connect=3ms service=14ms status=422 bytes=328
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue ended up being a Rails side one and didn't have to do with the order of the JSON being submitted.  I turned out the need for a CSRF token using the line right after `class DistributedHealthsController < ApplicationController` in my Controller:

```
skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token
```

This isn't recommended as it is a work around security, but if you want to exclude certain methods [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5669322/turn-off-csrf-token-in-rails-3) will show you how.

More discussion on the topic can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27098239/post-422-unprocessable-entity-in-rails-due-to-the-routes-or-the-controller) and some documentation on the topic can be found [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/RequestForgeryProtection.html).

Even though I am now able to do a POST to my rails app I am still getting a Error 500 in my Android Studio log that looks like this:

```
{"error":"Internal Server Error","status":"500"}
```

It doesn't seem to be hindering functionality right now so I am not going to lose any sleep over it.